# Prove that a 2 by 2 matrix C with tr(C)=0 can be written as C=AB-BA, where A and B are 2 by 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

"Let C be a 2 by 2 matrix with tr(C) = 0. Prove that C can be written as C=AB-BA, where A and B are 2 by 2 matrices."

Although it doesn't say, I think the field is complex number field. Also, this question can be solved without using determinants or considering invertibility since it's from a introductory chapter that hasn't discussed invertibility and determinants.
Please provide a hint, and not the answer, to the solution.

Comment: Uh, they can't both be $2\times3$, or else their product is undefined.

Comment: @Chris It seems, that in the head of the question is typo, because in the body is written $2 \times 2$.

Comment: @mathbb Seems likely, but I'll wait on OP editing. (Or the heat death of the universe, whichever comes first.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note :

A=  \begin{bmatrix} a & b  \\ 
                    c & d 
  \end{bmatrix}
 B=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a' & b' \\
    c' & d' 
  \end{bmatrix}
 C=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x & y \\
    z & -x 
  \end{bmatrix}
C=AB-BA implies that :

$ x=bc'- b'c \\ y = ab' +bd'-b'd-a'b \\ z=a'c+c'd-ac'-cd' $

This System has 8 unknows and 3 equations we need to reduce the number of solutions to 1 just to proove the existence of A and B. By fixing $ a'=c=c'=d=d'=1 $
Now we have :

$ x=b-b' \\ y= ab'-b' \\ z=1-a  $

And then you will find the value of $b, b', a$ , Now we have $ A , B $ such as $ C=AB-BA $ and $ Tr(C)=0 $ .

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would brute-force it: write $A$, $B$, and $C$ and try to solve for the variables of $C$ (where there is no redundancy) in terms of those of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I thought of that, and eventually got 3 equations with 8 unknowns. But it would be rather hard to solve it, since it's a 8-variable quartic equation that is nonlinear. Even if I did solve it, it doesn't have much mathematical inight.

Comment: Well, that is where you use the $8$ unknowns to your advantage... you have too many degrees of freedom, so that means that the equations are easier to solve that you think... you just need to find *some* $8$ numbers that will give you the $3$, not every combination of $8$.

Comment: Since it is in the begging of the book, it seems that this is the sort of thing that they want you to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be appropriate for the "beginning of the book", but anyway:

The condition of being a commutator is invariant under similarity, i.e. if
$C = AB-BA$ then $S C S^{-1} = (S A S^{-1}) (S B S^{-1}) - (S B S^{-1})(S A S^{-1})$.  Thus we can assume wlog that $C$ is in Jordan canonical form.
There are two possibilities:

$$ C = \pmatrix{a & 0\cr 0 & -a\cr}\ \text{and}\ C = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$
In each case we can find an $A$ and a $B$ that each have only one nonzero entry.